# Register of daily balance of valut

Tags: php, mysql, sql, math

I want to show daily balance of valut. For example 01.01. is balance 500€ and 02.01. I add 300€ som balance form 02.01. will be 800€

I have a code:

```
$balance = 'SELECT date, SUM(suma) AS DailyBalance FROM pokladna GROUP BY `date`';
    $result = mysql_query($balance);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<div>'.$row['date'].' <---> '.str_replace('EUR','€', money_format('%.2n', 
              $row['DailyBalance'])).'</div><br>';
        }
```

Its return

```
2017-01-01  157,10 €
2017-01-02  -52,00 €
2017-01-03  241,36 €
```

But I want

```
2017-01-01  157,10 €
2017-01-02  107,10 € (-52€)
2017-01-03  348,46 € (+241,36€)
```

Can anybody help? Is there way do this without creting extra table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery:

```
select date,
    (
        select SUM(suma)
        from pokladna q
        where q.date <= p.date
        ) as DailyBalance
from pokladna p
group by date
```